# python, running selenium with multiple treads in browser though web-based application

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently only able to access my school computers which do not allow downloads. I am trying to run selenium with mutable threads through a web-based python application. For example I have tried repl.it and online Juypterlab but have trouble. For example my code looks like this for real.it...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import _thread

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

def thread1():
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
  driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")

def thread2():
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
  driver.get("https://www.google.com")

_thread.start_new_thread(thread1, ())
_thread.start_new_thread(thread2, ())
```

my attempted juypterlab code looks like...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import _thread

def thread1():
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Applications/chromedriver')
  driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")

def thread2():
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Applications/chromedriver')
  driver.get("https://www.google.com")

_thread.start_new_thread(thread1, ())
_thread.start_new_thread(thread2, ())
```

my issue with repl.it is that I can not get mutable threads and with the online juypterlab I cannot get the path for my chromedriver to work. How can I get mutable treads of selenium to work at once while in a web-based environment? I think the main issue is not being able to get the PATH on a web-based application.